# How to integrate Cache2k caching with Spring MVC 4?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching, java-8, cache2k

I'm building a new Spring mvc project and I'm quite bit impressed to see the performance benchmark of **Cache2K**. Hoever, I couldn't find any article on how to configure it with the current **Spring MVC 4.2.4 and Java 1.8**

It'll be a great help if somebody would help me with this.

P.P. - I'm using JavaConfig with complete annotation support

Comment: 21 days passed yet to get a single helpful guide :(

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question because of wrong tracking filter settings. Although I am the author of cache2k I cannot answer your question, since I am not using Spring. If anyone wants to look at that I am happy to support this as best as I can and even set aside some budget to sponsor development. The relevant issue: https://github.com/cache2k/cache2k/issues/18

Answer (score 1):

cache2k is integrated well with Spring and Spring Boot. See the documentation section in [cache2k User Guide - Spring Framework](https://cache2k.org/docs/latest/user-guide.html#spring)